# how to create n x n size matrix with continuous numbes in python3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Is there any best way for me to create a n*n matrix as following? the only way I can think of is creating a n*n size list and chunk into n size sublist then apply to numpy. But all steps seems like redudent

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
num = range(0, n*n)
num = [list(num[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, n*n, n)]
x = np.array([i for i in num], np.int32)
#=> [[ 0  1  2  3  4]
#    [ 5  6  7  8  9]
#    [10 11 12 13 14]
#    [15 16 17 18 19]
#    [20 21 22 23 24]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `np.arange` to generate the sequence and then `reshape`:

```
import numpy as np

np.arange(n * n).reshape(n, n)
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```